# Is ADFS for internal CRM necessary if we already have an SSO for internet facing services?

Tags: adfs, single-sign-on, f5-big-ip, microsoft-dynamics-crm, crm

I never had to deal with ADFS until now so not sure if I get it correctly. We will have an implementation of Dynamics CRM inside our network soon and we already use F5 Big-IP APM for SSO with other applications.

Do someone know if we can just use our current SSO with Dynamics CRM for the mobile users? Or do we have to install ADFS even if it's not for users outside of the organisation?

Answer (score 0):

First, ADFS is not for users outside the organization.  Federation provides a way to authenticate without providing credentials to the application.  You should be able configure a relying party trust on the APM module, but you'd need the deployment guide for your crm version from f5